# How to fix rfkill blocking Wifi Adapter at every boot in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: intel, iwlwifi, rfkill

This is the output I get when running lshw -C network command only providing results for my Wifi card cause I dont use the ethernet as of this moment....

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 29
       serial: e0:d0:45:e6:2b:11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.3.0-060300-generic firmware=46.fae53a8b.0 9260-th-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:bf100000-bf103fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I have tried to use the rmmod and modprobe command to unload and reload the moduel then use the rfkill command to unblock the wifi which doesnt change anything after rebooting the system and running the rfkill list all command my wifi is still Soft Blocked. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to permanently stop this from happening.?